# Meaning of "turn someone out" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

It's from the fourth episode of the first season of *Breaking Bad*. Here it is:

> Policeman: Anyway, say hello to
> Domingo Gallardo Molina.
>
> A.k.a. Krazy-8. Way smarter than your average cheese eater.
>
> I **turned** him **out** when he was street level,
>
> but this dude's like The Jeffersons,
>
> moving on up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "turn someone out" in police/underworld/deviant slang can mean to make that person change roles or loyalties in a significant and relevant way. Gay people use it to discuss seducing someone formerly identifying as straight, and in a police context, including this one, to "turn out" a criminal is to recruit that person as a police informer.